# How do I create 3 equal sized boxes side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Let's say I have a container with with the following specs:

```
 .container {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 500px;
 }
```

Now in the middle I would like to add the 3 boxes aligned next to each other horizontally with the following specs:

```
 .box1 {
 background-color: #000;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 }
 .box2 {
 background-color: #999;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 }
 .box3 {
 background-color: #333;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 }
```

I tried using margin-top and margin-left on each but that was messy and it was a hassle getting them to look equally aligned with enough gutter between them. What's the best way to create this?

Comment: Add `float: left` to each box element then use margins to make them equally spaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put "float:left;" on each class.

```
 .container {
 float:left;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 500px;
 }

.box1 {
 float:left;
 background-color: #000;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 }
 .box2 {
 float:left;
 background-color: #999;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 }
 .box3 {
 float:left;
 background-color: #333;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  But how would I add space in between them? margin-left?

Comment: Yep... or margin-right. I dont' know what you are trying to do but I would add the margin-right:'X'px in the box1 and box2. Just do the math to konw how long can the margin be without exceed the container width (960px).

Answer (score 2):

```
.container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; height: 500px; }
.container [class*='box'] { width:300px; height:200px; float: left; margin-right: 30px; }
.container .box1 { background-color: #000; }
.container .box2 { background-color: #999; }
.container .box3 { background-color: #333; margin-right: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DRYBH/#fork

you can also try this minimum code

Answer (score 1):

For each of the .boxX items, add `display: inline` - this will fix the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property :

```css
display: inline-block
```

in all  `.box` classes

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code to put three tables side by side

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
    <style> 
    #example1 {
box-sizing: content-box;    
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
padding: 30px;    
border: 10px solid blue;
                    }


       }
      </style>
    </head>
     <body>

       <table><tr><td>
       <div id="example1"></div></td>
              <td><div id="example1"></div> </td>
         <td><div id="example1"></div> </td>

    </tr></table>


   </body>
        </html>
```